# Programmable Unlock file used in procedure

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am scanning images into a folder and using a file system watcher to grab the image and write to a database. The file is then moved to another folder.

Or that was the case until I decided to update the app,  now the file refuses to budge,  I get the standard error that the file is in use by another process.  I have attempted a lot of different methods to release the file without success including waiting for up to 5 minutes!  My code is here what can I do to force the move/delete of the file.

```
            Dim fs As New FileStream(Trim(e.FullPath), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
            Dim Data() As Byte = New [Byte](fs.Length) {}
            fs.Read(Data, 0, fs.Length)

           'copy to the database and close the file stream
           fs.close
           'attempt to move file
           System.IO.File.Move(e.FullPath, "\\\Processed Docs\" & BDate & DocType(5))
```

I have tried writing a loop:

```
          If System.IO.File.Exists(e.FullPath) = True Then
                        Dim proFile As String = e.FullPath
                        Data = Nothing
                        fs.Close()
                        For i As Integer = 0 To 10
                            Try
                                My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(proFile)
                            Catch ex As Exception
                                If i = 10 Then
                                    MsgBox("Failed delete")
                                Else
                                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
                                End If
                            End Try
                        Next
                       end if
```

Placing the saved file name into a collection,  then querying the collection later to get files that are older than 9 minutes then attempting to delete the file.

```
                     Dim oldfile = (From F In pfiles Where F.pdate < DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-3)                                    Select F).ToList
                If Not oldfile.count = 0 Then
                For i As Integer = 0 To oldfile.Count - 1
                Try
                    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(oldfile(i).fileName)
                Catch ex As Exception

                End Try

            Next
        End If
```

Comment: Maybe you could add your attemps to the question.

Comment: if the scanning process is in a different app than the FSW/Move app it might be the *other* app which has the lock.  Or it could be other code related to the first code block

Comment: I have manually added the file which has the same result!